# How to add\delete rows programatically from a table that binds with model data from controller in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Asp.NET MVC Page which has a model like

```
namespace Sample.Models
{
    public class ContModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        public string Customer { get; set; }

        public List<Order> Orders { get; set;}
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string OrderId;
        public string OrderDesc;
    }
}
```

I have successfully bound the model data using this article 
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp.net-mvc-getting-default-data-binding-right-for-hierarchical-views

The example given in the article uses 
`for` loop and `@Html.TextBoxFor` to form the table. Now I want to add\delete rows programatically.

So far all the samples I have referred are inserting rows using jQuery. And all the table rows are formed as a JSON string and passed to the controller using AJAX calls.

Is AJAX the only way to do this?. Is there a proper way to bind the data of newly added rows so that it will automatically passed on form submit using `POST` ?

Comment: Using form posts is the normal way of doing it... it's just that that involves a full page reload, so if you're not wanting to to have a full page reload, but rather have dynamically updating rows in your table as you add and delete without a full postback/page refresh, jquery and Ajax sounds an easy way to do that.
If you want the full post back and page reload for each row as they change, I'll happily write an example for you.

Comment: @Topher, Let the user add\delete any number of rows. Going to submit the form on submit button click. Not for every row change. So on submit button click I am okay with full post back and page reload. Curious to know the normal way of doing it without any jQuery or Ajax. Please provide code samples.

Comment: okay, yes that's possible as well without ajax. I'll give you an example shortly. It's a little more complicated with the delete, as you'll need to have a way to keep track of what's being deleted. but I can think of two ways which would work I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to start, disclaimer: I haven't tested the below code, it's possibly a little incomplete and might not work out of the box. But the main concepts are all there that I think will get you where you're wanting to go with a little applied thought.

Also, I'm not entirely sure about what happens if the index values of the items being bound to the list during model binding are not in order or are missing (for instance if you have a list of 3 orders and delete a row with index 2, you'll have a list with indexs 1 and 3 being bound, how does it create the list with 2 missing - you'll have to check this yourself.)

If you test it and find there is an issue, then you might have to rethink my quick attempt at storing the counter variable and maybe re-indexing the names of the items in the existing html when a row is deleted. - you can probably do away with the counter variable completely if you used a global variable in your javascript which will keep the value throughout the life of that page, but it's been a while since I've done something like that and while I seem to remember it working I can't say for sure.

**Deleting:** 
With deleting, you need to some how know *what* is being deleted. There's two ways that quickly come to mind;

1. You can check in your database once you've got the model in your controller, which items are in your database, vs which aren't in the list, and then remove those missing from the list from the database.
2. When an item is deleted, you store the `OrderId` in another hidden input in a comma separated string like "3,25,100", and have that bind to your model as well. That way, when you have the model in your controller, you can just split on the comma, and loop through the array and remove the corresponding orders.

I'm sure there's a number of other ways to do that though.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th><button id="AddOrder">Add Order></button></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count(); i++)
{
    var item = Model.Orders[i];

        <tr id="Order-@item.OrderId">
            <td>
                <button type="button" data-id="@item.OrderId" class="removeOrderBtn"></button>
                @* The trick to model binding with a list is the name attribute matching the Property Name on the model and giving it an index as below *@
                <input type="hidden" name="Orders[@i].OrderId" value="@item.OrderId" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.OrderDesc
                <input type="hidden" name="Orders[@i].OrderDesc" value="@item.OrderDesc" id="OrderDesc-@item.OrderId" />
            </td>
        </tr>

}
    </tbody>
</table>
@*Store the value of the last index in this input to keep track of it constantly*@ 
<input type="hidden" id="count" value="@(Model.Orders.Count()-1)">


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#AddOrder").on('click', function (e) {

        //get the counter input and store it because we're going to update the value later.
        var counterInput = $("#count");
        var counter = counterInput.val();
        counter++;
        //Assumed your new order description has an id of description.
        var description = $("#description").val();
        //Again you need to prepare your html so that the model binding will work by forming the name correctly.
        var newRow = "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='Orders[" + counter + "].OrderId' value='0' /></td><td <input type='hidden' name='Orders[" + counter + "].OrderDesc value=" + description +" /></td></tr>";
        var tableBody = $("#tableBody");
        //Append the new tr to the table body after the other rows (might be a better way to do this with append or something similar).
        tableBody[0].innerHTML = tableBody[0].innerHTML + newRow;

        //Update the counter stored in the input so that we can keep track of how many items we have in the list to try avoid duplicate numbers
        counterInput.val(counter);
    });

    $(".removeOrderBtn").on('click', function (e) {
        var id = e.target.dataset.id;

        var tableBody = $("#tableBody");
        tableBody.remove("#Order-" + id); // I think this takes a selector.
        var counterInput = $("#count");
        var counter = counterInput.val();
        counter--;
        counterInput.val(counter);

    });

</script>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Your tip about "trick to model binding" worked well. For deleting records instead of playing with the indexes and counter, I have added a "deleted" flag in the ````order class```` and marking this flag as true in case of deletion. Inside the controller I am ignoring deleted records.

Comment: @Niy Great, I knew you'd think of a better way :) glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

try this I hope it works for you

```html
<script src="//jsfiddle.net/mustafaozkaya/nfxz4ep2/18/embed/"></script>
```